# Website Font Changes When a New Element is Introduced

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to have each element retain its own font. Whenever I introduce an element with a different font layout, it overwrites the other proceeding elements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for every element a add css
Example:

```css
input
{
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

label
{
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input value="Example">
<label>Example</label>
```

Comment: True. But this is trivial and doesn't answer the question which itself needs more information.